# pressing f12 dev options and releasing it, I am able to edit the background of popup

Tags: html, css, dojo

I have used the css to process the background of css, it is working properly unless if f12 is pressed and when I click on popup button, it is taking the height from the window to the start of the developer options and not taking the whole height of the window

below is the css property:

```
.maskContainerDefault .awiTransparentSheet
{       
    position: fixed;
    *position: absolute;
    z-index: 900;
    opacity: 0.75;
    filter:alpha(opacity=75);
    left:0;
    top: 0;
    background-color:black;
    display: table;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0px;
}
```

I have tried using display : table but it doesn't work

Comment: CSS is not enough for this. There is more than just CSS to the popup right. Where is the JS that calculates the height & stuff

Comment: yes you are right, i  looked up the js and found that js was setting the inner width and height of the window to the background screen and that is why  on releasing the f12 i was able to edit the background screen. Thanks